# auto change birth date if given birth date given?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 input one is input for "Birth Date" and the one is for the Age, is there anyway, if I change the Birth Date, the Age input automatically change.

```
<input type="text" name="birthdate" value="07/24/1988" />
<input type="text" name="age" value="32" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the difference of current date and the date entered in years and then change the value of the age on `keyup` event like below

```js
function age(dt) {

  var diff = ((new Date().getTime() - new Date(dt).getTime()) / 1000) / (60 * 60 * 24);

  document.getElementById("age").value = Math.abs(Math.round(diff / 365.25));


}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="birthdate" value="07/24/1988" onkeyup="age(this.value)" />
<input type="text" name="age" value="32" id="age" />
```

Comment: You can *suggest* that the OP could accept an answer on their question, but its against SO guidelines to specifically ask them to accept your answer. (it is their choice and they don't have to accept any answer).

Comment: @FluffyKitten You should check this -https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer  .Asking for acceptance in polite way is actually acceptable :).Thanks

Comment: Nice!  However:
You can calculate `diff` in one line, or, at least, move the ` / 1000' to the second line.
Too many blank lines (I wouldn't use any).
The whole thing can be one line, and even without a function: directly in `onkeyup`.
Leap years seem to be ignored in your solution.

Comment: Shubh, that guidance is for a *new* user. The OP has been on SO for over 7 years. I've seen this brought up multiple times on both meta.SE and meta.SO over the years, and the general consensus is it is ok to guide *new* users who haven't accepted an answer before (here, the OP has) after *enough time has passed* for them to get answers (not just yours) and even more importantly that the time limit for accepting has passed ( which it hadn't in this case).

Comment: At the risk of being a pesk:  
`<input type="text" name="birthdate" value="07/24/1988" onkeyup="document.getElementById('age').value =
  Math.round(
    ( new Date().getTime() - new Date(this.value).getTime() )
    /
    (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * ( (400 * 365 +97) / 400) )
  );">`